# xcode 5 builds are heavier than xcode 6 builds

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, release-mode

I got device mode release builds of a static library for both versions of xcode 5.x and xcode 6.x. In case of simulator builds sizes of static library for both builds are almost same while for device builds there is a huge difference(xcode 6 - 940kb and xcode 5 - 1.5 MB).

Can anyone please help me to understand why there is so much difference in sizes for device release builds between both versions of xcode where as there is not much difference for simulator builds

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That it's because of new devices (6 and 6+) that are supported in new Xcode.
I would recommend to use 6.x version.